# can I use ftp site in <script src="ftp://">

Tags: javascript, html, protocols

Can I use FTP site in following code? Is it possible? The FTP site requires a username and password. How should I include username and password, if possible?

```
<html>
     <head>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="ftp://some_ftp_address"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you even do that? Or you link the internal address from your ftp or you link the website where the script is on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes, if there's no username/password required.

> The ftp site requires a username and password.

No, it's not possible (anymore).

> How should I include username and password, if possible?

You can't, and really really really shouldn't want to; you'd be giving them to anyone who wanted to look. It used to be part of the URL spec that you could include authentication information (e.g., a username and password) in the URL, but that was always a ***Really Bad Idea™*** (the username and password are then freely available to anyone who wants to look at your page, the network tab, etc.), and it's been deprecated. I believe support has actively been removed from browsers from responsible vendors.

Answer (score 3):

Just theoretical aspect: according to the specification of URL formats, **RFC 1738**, an FTP URL is of the form:

> ftp://user:password@host:port/path

To link to an FTP server that requires the user to log in, the format is:

```
<A HREF="ftp://user:password@server/pathname">...</A>
```

!!!But!!! In support of @T.J. Crowder reasonable post :

> For security purposes, it is highly recommended that you never include
>   both the username and password to a server within an HTML document. If
>   you use the syntax user@server/path, the user will be prompted to
>   enter his or her password in a dialog box.

Comment: I left the format out of my answer *on purpose*. Thought long and hard about whether to include it, but decided the harm outweighed the benefit.